# How to remove password from mongoose object?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I just want to update lastLogin property in user document every time a user logs in.

My password and salt are in the same object, and I have a pre save method attached which hashes the password.

The problem is when I try to save user during sign-in, pre save method executes and rehashes the password, which changes the password in the document.
How can I remove the password and salt property from mongoose user object before calling save method on user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `.save()`, use [`.findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) instead, if updating a single property is all you want to do:

```
// I'm taking a guess at your model name/fields here
User.findOneAndUpdate({ username : name }, { lastLogin : new Date() }, ...)
```